# How we calculate the intersection of two circles based on the tangents and straight line through their midpoints?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, circles

For two circles we have given:

- their midpoints $A=(x_A,y_A)$ and $B=(x_B,y_B)$
- the straight line $\overline{AB}$ through their midpoints by the angle $\delta_1$
- the two angles $\alpha$ and $\beta$ between $\overline{AB}$ and the tangents through each intersection point

The situation is depicted by the figure below.

It would be nice to have an elegant/efficient formula that calculates each intersection point $C=(x_C,y_C)$ based on $A$, $B$, $\delta_1$, $\alpha$, $\beta$. As an idea, I have drawn in the auxiliary angles $\delta_2=\delta_1-\beta$ and $\delta_3=\delta_1-180+\alpha$, whereby it would be great to not have them in the final formula.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**...Since $AC\perp BC$, let $M$ be the midpoint of $AB$ which is the centre of a circle which passes through $A,C$and $B$ and the other $C$.

To find the uppermost $C$, use a rotation matrix to rotate the vector $\overrightarrow{MB}$ anticlockwise through angle $\angle BMC=\pi-2\beta$ to get $\overrightarrow{MC}$.

Then you can get the coordinates of $C$ since $$\overrightarrow{OC}=\overrightarrow{OM}+\overrightarrow{MC}$$

For the lower $C$ change the rotation to clockwise.

You might like to try this for yourself. Ask if in doubt.

By the way you only need one of $\alpha$ or $\beta$ for this since $\alpha+\beta=\frac{\pi}{2}$ and you don't need any $\delta$ angles.

Comment: This solution looks very elegant - thank you. I played this night around with it too and came to the following system (hopefully it is consistent with your solution): $x_B\tan(\delta_1\pm\beta)-y_B=\tan(\delta_1\pm\beta)x_C-y_C$ and $x_A\tan(\delta_1\pm\alpha)-y_A=\tan(\delta_1\pm\alpha)x_C-y_C$, see http://sultanow.info/mathematics/elementary-geometry/intersection_2_circles.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Note that $\triangle ABC$ is a right triangle. Then $AC=AB\sin \beta$, $BC=AB\sin \alpha$

Thus, you can find coordinates of the intersection points by solving this system:
$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
(x_C-x_A)^2+(y_C-y_A)^2=AC^2 \\ 
(x_C-x_A)^2+(y_C-y_A)^2-AC^2=(x_C-x_B)^2+(y_C-y_B)^2-BC^2  \\ 
\end{array}
\right. 
$$
or
$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
(x_C-x_A)^2+(y_C-y_A)^2=AC^2 \\ 
-2x_Cx_A+x_A^2-2y_Cy_A+y_A^2-AC^2=-2x_Cx_B+x_B^2-2y_Cy_B+y_B^2-BC^2  \\ 
\end{array}
\right. 
$$Express $x_C$ or $y_C$ from the second equation and plug it into the first to get a quadratic.

Comment: Thank you for this straight-forward solution